# Let $Z_i(G)$ be the terms of the upper central series of $G$. Let $H \trianglelefteq G$. Show $Z_i(G)H/H \subseteq Z_i(G/H)$

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Let $Z_0(G) = \{ 1 \}$ and:

$$Z_{i + 1}(G)/Z_i(G) = Z(G/Z_i(G))$$

(as defined in dummit and foote).
I want to show that $Z_i(G)H/H \subseteq Z_i(G/H)$.
I can see it's true for $i = 0$ and $i = 1$, but I'm stuck in the inductive case because I have to work with quotients of quotients (and not in the form $(G/H)/(K/H)$ so no 3rd isomorphism theorem).

In other words, I have an element $zH \in Z_{i + 1}(G)H/H$.
I want to show that it is in $Z_{i + 1}(G/H)$, which is defined recursively as

$$Z_{i + 1}(G/H)/Z_i(G/H) = Z((G/H)/Z_i(G/H)).$$

Comment: Rewrite the recursive definition as $Z_{i+1}\left(G\right) = \left\{g \in G \mid ghg^{-1}h^{-1} \in Z_i\left(G\right) \text{ for all } h \in G \right\}$. Do you now see why each $Z_i$ is functorial wrt surjective homomorphisms (i.e., each surjective group homomorphism $f : G \to H$ sends $Z_i\left(G\right)$ into $Z_i\left(H\right)$ for each $i$)?